# Center content in clarity datagrid cell

Tags: css, angular, sass, vmware-clarity

I have a simple clarity datagrid with icons.

```
<clr-datagrid>
    <clr-dg-column>Severity</clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let alert of alerts; let i = index [clrDgItem]="item">
           <clr-dg-cell>
              <clr-icon id="severity-error" shape="minus-circle" class="is-solid"></clr-icon>
           </clr-dg-cell>
    </clr-dg-row>
</clr-datagrid>
```

[image]

How can I centered the icons in cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add style in `<clr-dg-cell>` cell tag.

```
<clr-dg-cell style="text-align: center;">
    <clr-icon id="severity-error" shape="minus-circle" class="is-solid"></clr-icon>
</clr-dg-cell>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in you style.css

```
clr-dg-cell {
text-align: center;
}
```

OR

You can use inline css

```
<clr-dg-cell style="text-align: center;">
    < your content>
</clr-dg-cell>
```